# Cover return Null in test class for code coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Here is my test class and class.

```
global class ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate implements ACN_NavigationProviderService {
global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList GetNavigationList (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList GoUp (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList GoPrevious (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList GoNext (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList GoLast (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList SavePreference (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}

global ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationList LoadPreference (ACN_NavigationLibrary.NavigationRequest request) {
    throw new ACN_NavigationLibrary.MethodNotImplementedException();
    return null;
}
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplateTest {

@testSetup
private static void testSetup() {

}

@isTest
private static void testGetNavigationList() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().GetNavigationList(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug(null);
    }
}


@isTest
private static void testGoUp() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().GoUp(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug(null);
    }
}


@isTest
private static void testGoPrevious() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().GoPrevious(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
     system.debug(null);
    }
}


@isTest
private static void testGoNext() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().GoNext(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug(null);
    }
}

@isTest
private static void testGoLast() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().GoLast(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug(null);

    }
}


@isTest
private static void testSavePreference() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().SavePreference(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
    system.debug(null); 
    }
}



@isTest
private static void testLoadPreference() {
    try {
        Test.startTest();
        new ACN_NavigationImplementationTemplate().LoadPreference(null);
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(Exception e) {
     system.debug(null); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this isn't possible, the return null will never be executed because you unconditionally throw an exception

Comment: You can put check of `Test.isRunningTest()` to throw the exception. If the condition is true then don't throw the exception.